# Advice on refactoring hosted services in a .Net 6 Web API into separate Azure Web Jobs

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, service, webapi

I have a .Net 6 Web API hosted on Azure App Service (Windows).

Over time, the API has grown to be a bit of an overweight monolith. I'd like to split it up into smaller chunks - micro-services could be an option - but for now, I thought a good candidate for the first step would be to refactor two hosted services in the API, and make them standalone Azure Web Jobs. These hosted services run once a day, so I would make it a triggered web job, on a schedule.

My first stumbling block was if the two Web Jobs should be projects in the same API solution, or if they should be two separate solutions. I decided to make them projects in the same solution. I hope that was the right approach...

Secondly, the hosted services share a DbContext with the rest of the API, as well as sharing a scoped service that's used in a few places in the API.

Regarding the DbContext, from my research, it appears it's ok to simply scaffold another DbContext in the Web Job projects - at least just for the database tables they require (so not necessarily scaffold the entire DbContext). This does mean there will be duplication as both the Web Job projects, and the main API project, will contain copies of the DbContext, but I've read in a few places that this is acceptable?

Regarding the scoped service that must be shared between the Web Jobs and main API, I thought I could refactor this service into a new DLL project in the solution, which could then be referenced by both the Web Job projects and the main API project.

The other option would be to to make it a micro service, with a REST interface. However, I thought since this service would not be used by any other solution other than the one at hand, and because I would imagine that if I made it a DLL it would run a lot faster as it will communicate with the other projects in process, it would be best (and easiest) to follow that approach.

However, this DLL would also need to have a copy of DbContext - at least just the tables it requires. So I'd have a DbContext in each of the four projects in the solution. That just doesn't sound right to me, and I thought could I not perhaps also make the DbContext a DLL that could be referenced by all projects? Is it even possible to register a DbContext service in Startup.cs when the class is in a separate DLL?

Sorry, I know this post is lengthy, and maybe I'm asking too many questions, but I'd love to hear your opinions. I don't want to go down the wrong path, only to have to undo everything at a later point.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I just realized I'm not even sure if .Net Core has a concept of DLLs like the .Net Framework has?